# Retrieving all the nodes from a given tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to make a method to collect all the nodes from a given tree passed as a parameter, but it seems that it isn't reading the left branch of any node.

The code I've developed so far is the following one.

```
private ArrayList<T> collect(AVLTree<T> tree, AVLNode<T> tRoot, ArrayList<T> l) {

    ArrayList<T> nodes = l;

    if (tRoot == null)
        return null;

    else {
        if (!nodes.contains(tRoot.element())) {
            nodes.add(tRoot.element());

            if (tRoot.getRight() != null) {
                collect(tree, tRoot.getRight(), nodes);
                return nodes;
            }

            else if (tRoot.getLeft() != null) {
                collect(tree, tRoot.getLeft(), nodes);
                return nodes;
            } 
        }
    }

    return nodes;

}
```

Hope you can help me out a little bit with this as I'm really stuck with it right now...

Comment: Are you still having problems progressing forward with this question?

Comment: @LingZhong All solved, thanks a lot for clearing my mind! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that are making the code not work.

1. You only check one branch of any node, meaning if right branch is being checked, the left one will not even if there are nodes in the left
2. You're returning too early. You don't need to return right after you check each branch. By doing so, you're skipping the left branches again if right branch exists.

The following fixes will work.

```
private ArrayList<T> collect(AVLTree<T> tree, AVLNode<T> tRoot, ArrayList<T> l) {

    ArrayList<T> nodes = l;

    if (tRoot == null)
        return null;

    else {
        if (!nodes.contains(tRoot.element())) {
            nodes.add(tRoot.element());

            if (tRoot.getRight() != null) {
                collect(tree, tRoot.getRight(), nodes);
            }

            if (tRoot.getLeft() != null) {
                collect(tree, tRoot.getLeft(), nodes);
            } 
        }
    }

    return nodes;

}
```

**EDIT:** After staring at the code a bit more. There are few places where code redundancy exists. They can be simplified and cleaned up to the following:

```
private ArrayList<T> collect(AVLTree<T> tree, AVLNode<T> tRoot, ArrayList<T> l) {

    ArrayList<T> nodes = l;

    if (tRoot == null)
        return null;

    if (!nodes.contains(tRoot.element())) {
        nodes.add(tRoot.element());
        collect(tree, tRoot.getRight(), nodes); // this is safe since null check exists at top
        collect(tree, tRoot.getLeft(), nodes);
    }

    return nodes;

}
```

Comment: `collect` should actually be a `void` method. As long as you pass in a non-null, empty list when making the initial call to `collect`, the list will eventually contain all the nodes without the need to return anything.

Comment: I agree, there are more things redundant here. Didn't want to make radical changes like function signature changes.